# Interact with a Python plot using keys instead of dragging

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

Using Matplotlib I made a 3D simulation of some moving objects. Currently, it is defaulted in a way such that if I drag my cursor across the screen I can move the plot around and see the objects in different perspectives. I was wondering if there is a way to change this such that instead of dragging, I can use the arrow keys on my keyboard to move the plot around in 3D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [key events](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/keypress_demo.html) to detect a key press and react accordingly.

The viewpoint of the 3D plot is given by `ax.elev` and `ax.azim` so it's just a matter of modifying those properties.

That being said, you will have to be careful not to clash with [existing keyboard shortcuts](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html#navigation-keyboard-shortcuts) (or redefine those if they interfere with the keys you were thinking of using).

Here is an example that shows how to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>-></kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd><-</kbd> keys to turn the plot around

```py
from matplotlib import cbook
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dem = cbook.get_sample_data('jacksboro_fault_dem.npz', np_load=True)
z = dem['elevation']
nrows, ncols = z.shape
x = np.linspace(dem['xmin'], dem['xmax'], ncols)
y = np.linspace(dem['ymin'], dem['ymax'], nrows)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

region = np.s_[5:50, 5:50]
x, y, z = x[region], y[region], z[region]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

ls = LightSource(270, 45)
# To use a custom hillshading mode, override the built-in shading and pass
# in the rgb colors of the shaded surface calculated from "shade".
rgb = ls.shade(z, cmap=cm.gist_earth, vert_exag=0.1, blend_mode='soft')
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=rgb,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_zticks([])


def on_press(event):
    print(event.key)
    if event.key == 'shift+right':
        ax.azim+=10
    if event.key == 'shift+left':
        ax.azim-=10
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_press)
```